# set Cell Language in apache POI workbook

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I am working on apache poi to create a workbook using XSSFWorkbook. but where i could not define a cell language for a number format.

[image]

I want to change the language to German.

Comment: Your picture shows the cell formatting dialog of `Libreoffice` or `Openoffice`but not the one of `Microsoft Excel`. But `apache poi` is not attempting to create files for  `Libreoffice` or `Openoffice` but for `Microsoft Excel`. So since `Excel` is not able setting language for each cell format - especially not for the `Number` cell format - this is not possible using `apache poi`.

Comment: Then how can i set a number formatting for german numbers in excel for apache POI ?

Comment: As said not possible using `Excel`. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e: "By default, Microsoft Excel uses the system separators that are defined in the regional settings in Control Panel." But what is **really** the requirement? If you have a number formatted as `#,##0.00` and you are opening this file using a German `Excel`, then "Excel uses the system separators that are defined in the regional settings in Control Panel". So a number `1234567.89` will be shown as `1.234.567,89`.

Comment: No i am trying to add a number in excel which is in german 1,234 as considered as 1.234 in english but the excel does not recognise it and display as 1234. which is incorrect as both the number formatting parameters are correct as of #,##0

Comment: "i am trying to add a number in excel ": How are you doing this adding? Show the code please.

Comment: I am also meeting the same requirement, how did you set the language for the workbook?